# Uploading Image from Angular 7 to Spring-boot

Tags: java, angular, image, file, spring-boot

I am trying to make Image transfer from my Angular application to Spring boot but i seem to not be able to make it work. When I am sending the POST request from angular with the file, spring boot doesn't seem to react at all,so I tested it with PostMan and I am getting the below error:

```
 "timestamp": "2019-05-05T06:45:26.907+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No primary or default constructor found for class java.io.File",
    "path": "/upload"
```

and in Spring Boot:

```
ERROR 18100 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for class java.io.File] with root cause
```

as well as Character decoding failed.

In the Spring output it seems to have guessed right the file type(image jpeg)
and it's name.

Here is Spring boot receiver:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value ="/upload")
     public void postImage(File file) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("received");
}
```

Later on I am planning on writing down the image in folder but for now I just want to get it.

Below is Angular part

```
<form>
    <div>Title:  <input type="text" id="input" [(ngModel)]="img.name" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> 
      <br>
      <input type="file" (change)='handleImages($event)' >
    </div> 
    <br>
   <button type="submit" class="confirm"(click) = 
'add()'>Confirm</button>
 </form>
```

component.ts:

```
handleImages(Event){  
      this.selectedFile = Event.target.files[0];
      console.log(this.selectedFile);
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/upload',this.selectedFile)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change param `File` to `MultipartFile`

```
//@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value ="/upload")
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public void postImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("received");
}
```

and wrap file content in FormData

```
handleImages(Event){  
      this.selectedFile = Event.target.files[0];
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", this.selectedFile);
      console.log(this.selectedFile);
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/upload',formData)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your suggestion, but Spring doesn't seem to receive the post request. the port and URL seem to be correct as Angular is able to get stuff from Spring. @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value ="/upload")
    public void postImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("received"); This is what Spring is listening to. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try change from @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value ="/upload") to @PostMapping(value = "/upload") ?

Comment: Hi, Making the suggested change worked when testing with PostMan(the image is received and saved as it should be), but from angular's side there is still complete silence e.g. spring doesn't even react when angular do post request with the FD. I made sure to console.log the formdata.get('file') and everything seems to be fine in the console. Any suggestions?

Comment: is there anything in console.log in console.log(this.selectedFile) ? in the network tab did you see post request run?

Comment: Hello, It turns out that Post request won't go unless I .subscribe to it. Your suggestion to look for it in the browser console made me realize that. Many Many thanks!

Comment: @HienNguyen Hi, I have the same request but I tryng to add an object too in the request, when I use just as parameter multipartFile is all ok, but when I add the object It give me that the request is not a MultiPartFile, do you have any solution?